# How do I use 도 (also, too)?

Tags: grammar, particle

So I somewhat know how to use 도 without changing verbs to their noun form but when it comes to using it to change verbs into their noun form, that's where any understanding goes out the window.

I don't understand why you need to change the verbs to their noun form to use 도 especially when they mean the same thing. For instance, I feel like "저는 영어를 가르쳐요" and "저는 영어를 가르치기도 해요" mean exactly the same thing. What's the point in changing them and how do I use them effectively?

Answer (score 4):

You always attach 도 to a noun, so if you want to use it with a verb, you have to use a noun form of that verb.
Also, depending on which word you attach 도 to, you emphasize that the "also/too" refers to the specific word.

> For instance, I feel like "저는 영어를 가르쳐요" and "저는 영어를 가르치기도 해요" mean exactly the same thing.

These sentences are not the same.

**The sentence without 도**

저는 영어를 가르쳐요

*I teach English*

A plain sentence without implying that this is an addition to something that was said previously.

**Adding 도 to a nominalized verb**

저는 영어를 가르치기도 해요

*I am also teaching English*

What this sentences really means is *"Teaching english is also something I do"*. Maybe you said something before about what you do with english, like rapping in English or studying English linguistics, but you want say, that you do this other thing with the object as well.

**Adding 도 to the subject/topic**

저도 영어를 가르쳐요

*I too each English*

In this situation you are saying that you yourself do something, too. Maybe someone said to you "I teach English", than this would be the right expression.

**Adding 도 to a the object**

저는 영어도 가르쳐요

*I also teach English*

Here you may have stated before, that you teach french or anything else, but you do the teaching also for another thing, in this case English. “I teach French. I also teach English.”

Answer (score 0):

Enumeration of things of almost same level in given question :

(1) What are you doing in shcool ?

너는 학교에서 뭐하니 ?

I am studying. 나는 공부 해요,

(And I chat with my friends, also. 그리고 친구와 수다도 떨어요)

(2) A : You have a great score in Korean test. For chat, I am going to school. Nowadays, it is unique my pleausre. 너 시험 잘봤더라. 나는 수다 떨려교 학교에 간다. 요즘, 그게 나의 낙이야.

B : I also chat with my friends in school frequently, too. 나도 (too) 종종 수다도 (also) 떨어.

(Additionally, my goal for school included study. 또한 학교 가는 목적으로 나는 공부를 포함시킨다.)